# Отношения Laravel роли и пользователи

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.7

есть таблица ролей - `roles`

```
id, title

public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class,'role');
    }
```

и таблица пользователей `users`

```
id,name,role

public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

у пользователя одна роль, у роли много пользователей, подскажите в чем ошибся, при `{{ $user->role->id }}` выдает неизвестный id

Comment: `$user->role->id` Вы id роли пытаетесь взять, что ли? Зачем? В чём вообще задача стоит? 
З.Ы. так-то лучше используйте уже готорый пакет для ролей, а не  занимайтесь изобретением  трёхколёсных велосипедов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Довольно распространённая ошибка.

> $user->role->id

Вы к свойству `role` обращаетесь, а не к связи. Т.е. к столбцу `role` в таблице `users`. Перепишите:

```
// Таблица пользователей `users`

id, name, role_id.
```

Теперь `$user->role` - это связь; `$user->role->id` - `id` роли пользователя.

Comment: Как он может "Вы к свойству role обращаетесь, а не к связи." если у users нет такого св-ва?